# What technology should I use for smart cards?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, computer-vision, iot, smart-card

I am an undergrad student majoring in CS. I recently took my FYP to upgrade my university's overall status in using advanced technology.
Put simply, what I proposed was to use an ALL-IN-ONE smart card for the students and faculty that they would use instead of a casual card that is in effect right now within the university.
What I want my Smart-Card to do:

1. Upon Entrance, the user will tap the card on a scanner or a reader which will read the data of the student and store it in the database.
2. For parking, student will tap the card on a reader while entering the parking lot and at tap again at the exit. Both his entrance and exit timing will be stored in the database.
3. Student will be able to access the library/ gym from those cards either.
4. Students will be able to pay from the card (this is the difficult one). The student will be able to use digital points stored in their cards to pay for their meals in the cafe.

In general, what software and hardware components would I want for them. The card will have a micro-chip. Someone said i should use the RFID technology. (Please guide me a little on that too).

For payment for points, how should i recharge it and what else would i need?

I am really confused about all of this, I have a deadline to submit a proposal for this in 3 days.
Any and all help will be really appreciated as your junior. :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds indeed like RFID/NFC is what you are looking for. Some introductory read [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-pn532-rfid-nfc/about-nfc), although it only scratches the surface.

In short, there are different types of RFID chips, some of which can be passkey-protected and some others not. Generally they store only little data (a few kB), but you can usually store data for several different applications on it in parallel. They come in many different forms, like cards, tags, buttons, stickers.

Adafruit, which I linked to, has various products that would allow you to prototype such a thing e.g. with an Arduino. For a system like you propose however, that would be a little more effort to set up of course. Especially if you need to link some kind of payment provider to it. But it is certainly possible.

Comment: So, like RFID is a chip that I can program my information on it? like, i get the basic idea.

Comment: Yes, it's a small chip with a small memory on it, enough for holding simple information (like user ID, tickets, or amount of money). Contactless payment cards use the same technology.

Answer (score 0):

For contactless applications RFID is what you are looking for.

As for the payment side of things: deploying a payment system from scratch is no small project.

If I were you I would get in touch with card issuers that have experience with **cobranding** (look up this keyword). The idea is to have a normal payment card with your logo, that will have a chip (very likely) and work according to the EMV standard. A standard bank card linked to a network like Visa or Maestro, meaning it would be a **non-proprietary** option that can be used in regular stores too. So the university could use ordinary payment terminals, *that may already be present in your organization* (the canteen).

So the card would be dual-technology: RFID + chip. Seems to me that you need both.

The big question is: are you allowed to use the bank card for other unrelated purposes, especially when there is personal data involved, possible GDPR issues etc. There are legal considerations that have to be discussed with the card issuer and probably your in-house legal department.

So yes, the payment feature is the tricky part in your project and that's why I would outsource this, unless you have a very strong reason to develop everything yourself. If you elect to become a provider of payment solutions, then quite probably you will be subject to all sorts of regulations, **compliance** rules and KYC. Plus **auditing**, **accounting**. There is money involved, so there is no room for amateurism here. You'll need legal guidance on this either way. Technology is not the biggest hurdle. The hurdle is to do it right and be compliant.

Comment: Hi, I actually get what you are trying to say. So I thought of something else, what if I change it a little bit like: There is a user in the cafe, a student goes to him and gives him $10. The user of the website that is integrated with the card will accept those $10 and in response, will provide the student with 10 points by transferring it into his card. The student can then use those 10 points to buy things in the cafe. I dont think so this type of method would need financial assistance and all.